# adding random characters to $_GET variable

Tags: php, mysql, get

I was just wondering if it was possible to add random characters to the variable I am passing to the second page. I want this because if the user changes the value in the url, then the system is gonna mess up because I am inserting data to database based on the message id. I can't use session because the first session is overriding the others.

If I have something like `view_inbox.php?messageid=2` then the user can change it to something `view_inbox.php?message=4`.

So is it possible to have some random characters like

`view_inbox.php?messageid=GXLSsd2sdcds`? The id is coming from database.

```
echo"<a href='view_inbox.php?messageid=".$row['id']."'>".$row['from_user']."</a>";
```

view_inbox.php

```
$id = $_GET['messageid'];
```

Comment: " I can't use session because the first session is overriding the others." that makes no sense, and sessions sounds like a much better approach. ... `$_SESSION['messageid']=2;` ...

Comment: How are random characters going to a) help you and b) stop someone from fiddling with it? I think you need to re-think your real problem.

Comment: Generally URL manipulation is avoided by sanity checking input variables before displaying data to the user, I.E. checking if the ID in the url is a message that the user is allowed to view and displaying an error message if it is not.

Comment: @Dagon it's like on the first page `inbox.php` all messages will be listed, and when the user selects the message to see the details, it will show for the first one. But after the first one if the user selects the another message then the message detail is the same.

Comment: then your not correctly changing the session variable when the message is selected. why not fix that, than try a worse apporach

Comment: Why do you care if the user changes the messageid parameter? No matter what he sets it to, he should only be able to access his own messages, your database queries should check that.

Comment: @Dagon what i did was `$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id']; then on the second page just $id = $_SESSION['id']; how do I change the session?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches.

1. You should be checking security rules on which rows/entities the user is allowed to access. Put these rules in a common procedure/function in your code, so you can check them consistently.
2. You can also "obfuscate" or encrypt the ID, in a way the server can reverse but is not easy/obvious for the client. Operations could include multiplying by a prime number (say 23) modulo 2^32, XOR by a constant, outputting it in base-64, perhaps with a lowercase 'x' in front.

For the second approach:

```
function encodeKey ($key) {
   $multiplied = $key * 23;
   $packed = pack( "N", $multiplied);
   $base64 = base64_encode( $packed);
   return $base64;
}
function decodeKey ($text) {
   $packed = base64_decode( $text);
   // then unpack, divide etc.
   return $key;
}
```

Comment: thanks but can you show me with one example. what I do on page one and two? I have no idea about this.